# Can't find javax.ws.rs package in jdk

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jax-rs

I'm trying to get into JAX-RS.
My project jdk is set to 1.7.03.
Does there have to be definitions of annotations for JAX-RS(javax.ws.rs)?
If not, where I can find them?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These classes ([*JSR 311: JAX-RS: The JavaTM API for RESTful Web Services*](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311)) are not part of the JDK. You need to include appropriate JAR file to your CLASSPATH. You can find the API e.g. in [maven repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/).

Also check out [apache-cxf](/questions/tagged/apache-cxf), [jersey](/questions/tagged/jersey) (reference implementation), [resteasy](/questions/tagged/resteasy) from JBoss, [restlet](/questions/tagged/restlet) and few other JAX-RS implementations.

Comment: If they're not part of the JDK, then why are the classes defined in the Java JDK? See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html

Comment: Because they are part of the JavaEE specification and not part of the base Java SDK.

Comment: Jersey 2.25.1 includes `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar`, which contains the classes that you need.  You can download the `Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle` from https://jersey.java.net/download.html.

Answer (score 12):

Try:
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-spec/index.html

Download: javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.rev.A.jar

Then add to your Project Properties(YourProjectName)->Libraries->Add JAR/Folder

Comment: Better late than never. Maven rep points to `JSR 311` and today we are at `JSR 339-JAX-RS-2.0`

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter what your JDK is set to.

Go here= http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxwsrsjar.htm

Or type in "Download javax.ws.rs" into Google.

Download “javax.ws/javax.ws.rs.jar.zip”

[image]

Unzip to your desktop. The resulting file should be a jar file.
Open your project preferences and add it as external jar.

[image]

[image]

Select your javax.ws.rs.jar file from your Desktop.

Click “Apply” and then “OK”.

Now you should be able to use the javax.ws.rs libraries. You can test it by typing "import javax.ws.rs.GET;" in one of your Java classes.