# Java - How to use a existing Enum inside class

Tags: java, enums

Can someone give me an example how to use this enum. I'm trying to find out what I need to import and how I can use the methods of the following Enum:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html

Comment: codesearch or similar could help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the correct package containing the `enum` definition. In this instance `javax.ws.rs`. Visit this post to know where to find it.

[Can't find javax.ws.rs package in jdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869977/cant-find-javax-ws-rs-package-in-jdk)

After you have added the .jar to your `CLASSPATH` you can simple import it

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes one example in JSON:

```
public Response retrieveSomething(String uuid) {
    Entity entity = service.getById(uuid);
    if(entity == null) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Entity not found for UUID: " + uuid).build();
    }
    String json = //convert entity to json
    return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In many respects an enum is just like z regular class; the answer is practically the for how to use an enum as how to use a class:

Step 1: import the enum to your program:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
```

Step 2: Het a reference to an instance (unlike regular classes, you can't *create* an instance - that is done for you by the JVM), either from the enum:

```
Status status = Status.OK;
```

or as the returned value of a method:

```
Status status = response.getStatus();
```

Step 3: Invoke a method:

```
int code = status.getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example using the Status enum:
First import Response:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

Then your code...

```
public Response create() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).build();
}
```